# On zipfile read of shapefile from URL, fault for initial value not str

Tags: python, macos, jupyter-notebook, stringio, python-zipfile

Using Python 3.5, following example for reading shapefile zipfile from URL and updating for P3.5.  Code is below.  I've looked at other cases and attempted to append .decode('utf-8') and that does not help.

```
    dls = "https://github.com/ItsMeLarry/Coursera_Capstone/raw/master/tl_2010_25009_tract00%202.zip"
print('Downloading shapefile...')
lynntracts = ZipFile(io.StringIO(urllib.request.urlopen(dls).read()))
print("Done")
```

Error code is:
TypeError: initial_value must be str or None, not bytes

If I put in .decode('utf-8'), ala:

```
lynntracts = ZipFile(io.StringIO(urllib.request.urlopen(dls).read().decode('utf-8')))
```

I get the following message:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa4 in position 57: invalid start byte

Putting the decode() on the outside of the io.StringIO call has no impact on the original problem.  I'm lost.  What can I try or what do I need to study?  Thanks.

Also, I'm trying to implement a procedure that doesn't create a file on disk, temp or otherwise, because the relationship between Jupyter and Macos prohibits accessing files on disk.  That's another problem that no-one has been able to solve yet.

Answer (score 1):

```
import urllib.request
import io
from zipfile import ZipFile

dls = "https://github.com/ItsMeLarry/Coursera_Capstone/raw/master/tl_2010_25009_tract00%202.zip"
print('Downloading shapefile...')
lynntracts = ZipFile(io.BytesIO(urllib.request.urlopen(dls).read())) -----> Edited Line
print("Done")
```

Use BytesIO instead.

StringIO takes in a string while the data that you are passing it is bytes.

Comment: I made the change and it seems to work, but I lurched onto the next problem. They may be related. I'm posting it separately.